# Firewall for private network

Tags: ubuntu, security, firewall, iptables

Here is my setup:

All nodes are running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS

I have a machine, **node1**, that acts as a proxy server for a private network. It forwards all incoming connections on port 80 and 443 to my webserver, **node2**, which has a private ip of `10.182.33.141` and no public IP.

I have several other nodes: **node3** is a database server, **node4** is a memcached server, etc. They all have a private IP and no public IP.

I want **node1** to act as a firewall as well, while still forwarding ports 80 and 443 to **node2**.

What is the BEST way to configure **node1** to begin acting as a firewall? What are some ways to test said firewall for security?

Any direction is greatly appreciated! I'm sorry if this has been asked before, I did search and did not find what I was looking for.

FOR REFERENCE: (iptables -t nat -L)

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             node1               tcp dpt:www to:10.182.33.141:80 
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             node1               tcp dpt:https to:10.182.33.141:443 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
MASQUERADE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

iptables -L is currently empty.

Comment: You mean you want to add an public IP address to node1?

Comment: What do you mean, "you want node1 to begin acting as a firewall"?  It node1 was is the only system with a public ip address then it's already acting as a firewall of sorts by passing traffic on ports 80 and 443 on to your internal systems.  What sort of additional behavior do you want?

Comment: I want it to deny everything else

Answer (score 1):

A few months back, I was trying to establish a similar setup. I eventually abandoned the idea and went back the old, less flexible firewall I had before. I can give you a few pointers, but I can't answer such a broad question readily.

- Know the difference between masqurading, Source NAT, and Destination NAT.
- Know what each of the Netfilter tables is for, and which chains are in each
- Allow all outgoing traffic (if you trust your users)
- Allow packets of existing connections to continue by using the contrak or state modules
- DNAT incomming traffic to the servers/ports you want to expose to the world
- Make sure your firewall (**node1**) allows packet forwarding: `echo >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward 1`

That's about where I stopped; I had trouble making this box coexist with another machine on our network, which is why I can't say I have a solution.